# Reading UTF String on okio that was sent using DataOutputStream writeUTF() method

Tags: java, android, utf-8, okhttp, okio

I am using okhttp and okio on my current android project to get and read some binary stream I am sending , within the stream I am sending some UTF values using the method

```
DataOutputStream.writeUTF().
```

the "okhttp" gives you 2 options either get the inputStream and thus you can use the method DataInputStream.readUTF() directly .

the other option is to get the stream as BufferedSource and use its methods to read the data , i was surprised that the method to read the UTF need you to supply it with the byte count .

```
String readUtf8(long byteCount)
```

to read the UTF coming from the server i added the following methods

```
public static String readUtf(BufferedSource bufferedSource)throws IOException {
       int length =  readShortAsUnsignedInt(bufferedSource);
       return  bufferedSource.readUtf8(length);
    }

    public static int readShortAsUnsignedInt(BufferedSource bufferedSource)throws IOException {
        return bufferedSource.readShort() & 0xffff;
    }
```

is this the right approach to do this ?